# Thread Pool C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    someJob();
}
```

I want to run this function only with 5 threads, how can I do it?
I can't use any external library.

What I've tried is to make an array with 5 threads and if the index is equal to 5 to wait all threads and do it again, but I'm sure there is another way to do that:

```
std::thread t[THREAD_COUNT];
int j=0;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    t[j++] = std::thread(someJob);
    if (j == THREAD_COUNT)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < THREAD_COUNT; k++)
        {
            if (t[k].joinable())
                t[k].join();
        }
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion? (I can't use boost)

Thanks!

Comment: It is std::thread

Comment: Start each thread with a function that calls `someJob` in a loop 20 times. Not the best way, but the simplest. Else use a threadpool with 5 threads pulling jobs from a queue, containing `someJob` 100 times.

Comment: I didn't want to add this to my answer, but you can also you my own library, concurrencpp which guarantees `concurencpp::async` runs on a threadpool : https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need to test whether those threads are joinable. You haven't detached them, so they are joinable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function that tests your thread array to find a vacant thread to run each successive job on. Something like this:

```
// synchronized output to prevent interleaving of results
#define sync_out(m) do{std::ostringstream o; o << m << '\n'; std::cout << o.str();}while(0)

void someJob(int id)
{
    sync_out("thread: " << id);
}

template<typename Job>
void start_thread(std::vector<std::thread>& threads, Job&& job)
{
    // find an ended thread
    for(auto&& thread: threads)
    {
        if(thread.joinable()) // still running or waiting to join
            continue;

        thread = std::thread(job);
        return;
    }

    // if not wait for one
    for(auto&& thread: threads)
    {
        if(!thread.joinable()) // dead thread (not run or already joined)
            continue;

        thread.join();
        thread = std::thread(job);
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::thread> threads(5); // 5 threads

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        start_thread(threads, [=]{someJob(i);});

    // wait for any unfinished threads    
    for(auto&& thread: threads)
        if(thread.joinable())
            thread.join();
}
```

Comment: You could be waiting for a thread that takes longer, while the other threads are done.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Of course. There are more complicated and sophisticated ways to improve efficiency.

Comment: The question is not as trivial as it seems.  Not until we see something like join_until()  in the stl.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I think the question covers a large set of problems that are well serviced by my solution. It is just a simple *pipeline* problem. Sure you can find more sophisticated solutions that may provide better *throughput* in some situations. But the question hardly demands that.

Comment: I wasn't trying to downplay you solution, sorry if you understood it that way...  I was simply stating a fact.  This problem is _not_ trivial.  Even my solution is not so perfect, since I detach threads, and there could be more than 6 threads running at some point.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Well, you are right. Solving the problem of deciding which thread to wait for is definitely non trivial. Especially if you also want to remove blocking.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Thread Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool).

Specifically, you might use the C++ Thread Pool Library [CPTL](https://github.com/vit-vit/ctpl), with which  your code would look like this:

```
ctpl::thread_pool p(2 /* two threads in the pool */);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    p.push(someJob, "additional_param");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I cant use any external library

Comment: @JustASK: If this is a homework assignment, you should clearly state it in the question.

Comment: The library also seems to be unmaintained. 2 years since last commit and 4 open issues that are up to 2 years old.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `std::async` for that.

If you want to execute this function 100 times in 5 different asynchronous actions , then each asynchronous function will execute the function 20 times:

```
std::vector<std::future> results;
results.reserve(5);
for (auto i = 0; i< 5 ;i++){
   results.emplace_back([]{
     for(auto j = 0; j < 20 ; j++){
       doSomeFunction();
     } 
   });
}

for (auto& f : results){
    f.get();
}
```

the same code can be modified to use naked `std::thread`.

Comment: You don't know that the function takes the same amount of time with each invocation.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) will allow you to do this trivially, while hiding the entire threadpool. Most compilers have build in support, but consult your manual for the specific options. (gcc simply requires passing `-fopenmp` as an option).

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    someJob(i);
}
```

will then split your work over 5 threads. If you leave out `num_threads(5)` it will choose a number of threads itselve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to implement a thread pool on the fly, while staying safe.

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>

void someJob() { /* some lengthy process */ }

int main()
{
    const size_t THREAD_COUNT = 5;
    std::vector<std::thread> threadPool;
    std::mutex mtx;               // to block access to the pool

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    {
        {
            // add new thread to the pool.
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            threadPool.emplace_back(std::thread([&mtx, &threadPool]()
            {
                someJob();

                // task is done, remove thread from pool
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                threadPool.erase(
                    std::find_if(threadPool.begin(), threadPool.end(), 
                    [](std::thread& x) 
                    { 
                        if (x.get_id() == std::this_thread::get_id())
                        {
                            x.detach();  // have to call detach, since we can't 
                            return true; // destroy an attached thread.
                        }
                        return false; 
                    })
                );
            }));
        }

        for (;;)
        {
            // wait for a slot to be freed.
            std::this_thread::yield();
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            if (threadPool.size() < THREAD_COUNT)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // wait for the last tasks to be done
    for (;;)
    {
        std::this_thread::yield();
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); // works fine without.. but...
        if (threadPool.empty())                // <-- can't call join here, since detached 
        {                                      // threads are not joinable()
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```