# Join threads created recursively

Tags: c++, multithreading, recursion

I have a function that basically fetches a data from a database, then parse this data and fetches others data to which it is dependant, and so on...

The function is thus recursive, and I want to use multithreading to do so.

To simplify the problem, I just writed a dummy program, just for expressing the "spirit" of the function:

```
void DummyFunction(std::vector<std::thread>& threads, int& i)
{
    ++i;

    if (i < 10)
        threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() { DummyFunction(threads, i); }));
}

int main()
{
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        int i = 0;
        DummyFunction(threads, i);

        // Coming here, "DummyFunction" is still running and potentially creating new threads
        // Issue is thus we may enter the for loop when we still don't have the actual number of threads created
        for (std::thread& thread : threads)
        {
            thread.join();
        }
}
```

The issue comes from the need to wait for all the threads to finish running before going any further (hence the for loop to join the threads). But of course, since the "DummyFunction" is still running, new threads can be created and so this way it can't work...

Question is, how can I design such thing properly (if there is a way...)? Can we actually use multi threading recursively?

Comment: Maybe each `DummyFunction` could wait for the threads its created. I would seriously advise for non-global passing of results and `thread`s themselves. Just let each function spawn its threads, wait for the results, return them. Holding global multi-threaded state is pita...

Comment: In addition to Sam's answer: `DummyFunction(threads, i);` should be `DummyFunction(threads, std::ref(i));` and you would also need to synchronize reading/writing to `i` inside the function.

Comment: Your example literally does _nothing_ except create ten ephemeral, do-nothing threads. If you would add just one line—a call a function named `DoSomeUsefulThing()`—that would help people to better understand the "shape" of the recursion.

Comment: P.S.: You should consider using a [_thread pool_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). Unfortunately, the C++ `std::` library for some reason has neglected thread pools for a long time, but [_this answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45631135/801894) mentions a third-party, thread-pool library. Or, you could use the thread pool that is implicit in the [`std::async(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) function.

Answer (score 3):

If you have C++20 available consider using the new thread that automatically joins on destruction. It goes by the name [jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) and will save you all the trouble from having to manually join threads.

Comment: Looks like the C++ standard library designers had some feedback from the real world :) `std::jthread` looks much more real-worldy than `std::thread`

Answer (score 2):

Try a thought experiment: add an `else` clause to your `if` statement:

```
if (i < 10)
{
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() { DummyFunction(threads, i); }));
}
else
{
    // do something here
}
```

Once you make that change, a few minutes' worth of thinking will reach the following conclusion: the "do something here" part gets executed exactly once, in one of the execution threads, after all of the execution threads get created.

Now, the solution should be very obvious:

1. Add a mutex, a condition variable, and a boolean flag. You can either make them global; pass them as additional parameters into `DummyFunction`, or, better yet: turn your `threads` vector into its own class containing the vector, the mutex, the condition variable, and the boolean flag, and pass that in recursively instead of just the vector.
2. `main()` locks the mutex, clears the condition variable, and after `DummyFunction()` returns it waits on the condition variable until the boolean flag is set.
3. The "do something here" part locks the same mutex, sets the boolean flag, signals the condition variable, and unlocks the mutex.

Once you reach this point, you will also suddenly realize one more thing: as is, you have different execution threads all attempting to `push_back` something into the same vector. Vectors are not thread-safe, so this is undefined behavior. Therefore, you will also need to implement a separate mutex (or reuse the existing one, this looks eminently possible to me) to also lock the access to the vector.